# email signature in Ms Outlook displayed as attachment

Tags: outlook

I am trying to send an email with a picture signature using Ms Outlook but when the recipient receive the message, It appears like it has an attachment even if i have not attached anything. Please help.

Comment: are you sending this via code, or just via outlook?  If just via outlook and inserting the signature then this is not the correct place for the question.

Comment: i am sending it Microsoft Outlook without code. and this is not the right place then show me where to place the question